# "It's say to say"

Tags: phrases, slang

I recently came across an online forum where a reader responded using the phrase, "It's say to say..." where I would expect to see, "It's safe to say...".  I thought perhaps it was a typographical error, but a quick google search revealed that the phrase "It's say to say..." is being used occasionally in this context.  Is this new?  Should this be considered slang or another instance of devolution of the English language?

Comment: [Yes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=safe+to+say%2Csay+to+say&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csafe%20to%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csay%20to%20say%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Wow!  "safe to say" has suffered a 75% drop over the past 100 years!  I wonder what that's about.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  I'll offer a third possibility: the correspondent *meant* to use "It's ***easy*** to say," but *typed* "It's ***asy*** to say," and then autocorrect happened.  (That might be unlikely, based on context, but you didn't provide the context, so I can't tell.)

Comment: @Scott [context](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22say+to+say%22).  Also note this NGram, which shows an uptick in the last decade or two: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=safe+to+say%2Csay+to+say&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csafe%20to%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csay%20to%20say%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Looks like most of the "say to say" instances in NGram are "to say to say" accidental repetitions.

Comment: @BigAl yes, thanks for pointing that out for people who won't or can't follow the links.  There are many terms where the original sense seems to get lost as kids learn them and don't always get corrected as they grow; this is a new one to me, but we also have *neck in neck, tow the line, take the reigns, baited breath, ...*  See [the eggcorn database](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/).  You should submit *say to say!*

Comment: Plus a few where the second instance is quoted: «How do you say “to say” in language *X*?» and «What’s another way to say “to say the very least”?»

Comment: @scott, sure, there are those.  Also note the difference in the search results for [*"it's say to say"*](https://www.google.com/#q=%22it%27s+say+to+say%22) and [*"its say to say"*](https://www.google.com/#q=%22its+say+to+say%22).  It's perhaps not surprising that the phrase is often used with the wrong *its.*

Comment: @phoog: One of my un-favorites: *for all intensive purposes.* Then again, I like the joke about how the smart cat hunted mice.

Comment: I don't know what google search you did, but searching "say to say: returns only accidental repetitions, Things like "How to say 'to say' in Russian?", and this question in second place.

Comment: @DJClayworth see my earlier comment; I did an exact phrase search including the word *it's* and then another one with *its.*  Example **Well it's say to say that I won't be getting a yellow pixie cut anytime soon but loved this look for the day*

Comment: Maybe it was "speech to text" and the computer misheard **safe to say**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a phrase and any instance you find is likely an error.

[The ngram viewer finds no instances, for example.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It's%20say%20to%20say&year_start=1985&year_end=2016&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)

Comment: If this is a new usage, and ngram only "looks" up to 2008, is it a good tool to use in this case? I'm not being rude-I am still a novice with this thing.

Comment: @PeterK. but I think the data only cover through 2008, so if you put a later end date, there's no difference.  It's certainly nonsense; the end-date question is more relevant to that of when it arose.